# Problem using an extension to load image into a custom cell

Tags: swift, image, cell, extension-methods

My last question for today. I'm too newby with swift to know what's happening but my problem is as follows:

I've use the next extension to load an image from a URL and it works when I use it in a imageView in a normal view, but when the imageView is inside of a custom cell It doesn't recognize de method so I can`t use the extension. What am I doing wrong? Thank you all in advances.

My code for the extesion is:
import UIKit

```
extension UIImageView {

func loadFrom(URLAddress: String) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: URLAddress) else {
            return
        }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let loadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        self?.image = loadedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the table where I try to use it into a custom cell:

```
  import UIKit
    
    class EventosCustomCellController: UITableViewCell {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var imEvento: UIView!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var txtNombreEvento: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var txtFechaEvento: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var txtEstadoEvento: UILabel!
    }
    
    class ListaEventosTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title = "Eventos"
            
        }
    
        // MARK: - Table view data source
    
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            
        }
        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
    
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return eventos.contarEventos()
        }
    
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototipoCeldaEvento", for: indexPath) as! EventosCustomCellController
            
            let evento = eventos.buscarEventoPorID(id: indexPath.row)
            cell.txtNombreEvento?.text = evento?.nombre
            cell.txtFechaEvento?.text = evento?.fecha
            cell.txtEstadoEvento?.text = evento?.tipo
            if evento?.tipo == "deportivo"{
                cell.backgroundColor = .blue}
            else if evento?.tipo == "cultural"{
                cell.aplicarFondoDegradado()
                cell.backgroundColor = .green}
            else{
                cell.backgroundColor = .red}
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
               cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            //There is no method loadFrom when I try to use as follows
            cell.imEvento?.loadFrom(URLAddress: (evento?.imagenes![0])!)
            return cell
        }
        
    
        
        // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
            return true
        }
       }
```

After updating code my problem is that the cell isn`t growthn appropiately
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you better use `UIImageView` instead of `UIView` because your extension for `UIImageView` and you can access to this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imEvento: UIImageView!
```

and then it is good to override the `prepareForReuse` method like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    imEvento.image = nil
}
```

you can read more about the [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) method from apple documentation

Comment: Thank you! It works but my problem now It's that the height's cell is shorther that it's context I was sure that the cell would adapt its height to fit with their content. And the contrains are ok

Comment: you can update the question and add an image of the result with your constraint code which I help to you

Comment: @hassam mahdiabadi done! It's not about constraints is about cell size

Comment: I'm glad it's resolved, If you would, you can use the upvote button :-)

Comment: Done again sorry!